# Why doesn't tools:listitem work not properly?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

I have such a list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_actor_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_view_avatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view_avatar"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_view_ocsar"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view_ocsar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_ocsar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/oscar_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:src="@drawable/oscar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the preview works like expected:

[image]

And listview is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_actor">

</ListView>
```

but why doesn't listview preview with `tools:listitem` work not properly?

[image]

Why does only the first item of listview's preview look like item's preview, but others looks differently?..

Comment: This is better if you use `LinearLayout` for this.

Comment: Your code looks fine in my preview. Have you tested it with real data?

Comment: @mTak, yes, on real device with real data this roster looks fine, just as expected. So I suppose that the problem is exactly in Android Studio preview.

Comment: @Ksenia as i said in my preview it looks fine. Maybe you need an update

Answer (score 0):

Remove marked point

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_avatar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_actor_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_view_avatar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view_avatar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_view_ocsar"  //remove this line
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view_ocsar"   //remove this line
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:maxLines="1"
    tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_ocsar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/oscar_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"  //remove this line
    android:src="@drawable/oscar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will work only to rearrange properly, but this is not the best way.

Answer (score -1):

The `LinearLayout` is a lot easier to use in your case because we can use `layout_weight` to consume the remaining space in the center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_actor_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_ocsar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/oscar_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:src="@drawable/oscar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```